# Django: Unable to load embedded PDF dynamically

Tags: django

I'm trying to display a PDF (uploaded by the user) in my template in an embedded frame. What's strange is that the url only works if I use an anchor tag  but not if it's embedded. I get :

**Template**

✓ Works

```
<a href="{{booking.lease.url}}">Lease</a>
```

(url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/leases/lease_CZORz79.pdf)

X Doesn't Work

```
<embed src="{{booking.lease.url}}" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">
```

(url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/leases/lease_CZORz79.pdf) (ie, exact same)

[image]

**Views.py**

```
def review_lease(request, pk):
    booking = Booking.objects.get(id=pk)
    context= {
        'booking': booking,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/review_lease.html', context)
```

**Settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

**Models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=BOOKING_STATUS_OPTIONS, default=0)
    tenant = = models.ForeignKey('TenantProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='booking')
    lease = models.FileField(upload_to='leases/', null=True)
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but here are a couple of things to try.  Does adding the |safe filter do any good?  Also, I'd be curious what the console and/or network tabs have to say in the inspector.  Maybe there is an error message there that can help.

Comment: Screenshots from the devtools console / network tab would definitely help. I also can imagine problems with the `type="application/pdf"` on `embed`, but Django not setting that Mime-Type on the PDF response properly. So either try removing the type attribute or make django return proper MIME headers